# How to include all .jar files in directory in Jetty 9.1.1

Tags: java, jetty, classpath

We are in the process of upgrading from Jetty 9.0.6 to 9.1.1 and are working through the configuration changes to complete the transition.  Our application has numerous web contexts deployed, all of which use a common set of libraries (apache commons, logging, specific db, etc) located in an external directory (i.e. - outside of the Jetty deployment).

In Jetty 9.0.6, we included a parameter on start-up which referenced the top level directory for these common libraries:

```
java -jar .\start.jar lib=M:\common\lib
```

In the cutover to Jetty 9.1.1 the flag has been changed to **--lib**.  Using the **--list-configs** we've verified that the directory is in the classpath created by start.jar.  However, when the application is started, we are getting numerous ClassNotFound issues.  All of these errors are for classes contained in jar files that are located in the common library.

This makes me believe that the flag is for either un-jarred classes or a list of specific jar files.  We've also tried using the M:\common\lib* and m:\common\lib*.jar to no avail.

I've searched for any reports of a similar issue, but having found none am asking the question.  Does anyone know how to pass all .jar files located in a directory to Jetty 9.1.1 on startup?

Comment: The only thing I've been able to come up with thus far is to enable the **ext** module and put all the libraries in **lib\ext** directory.  Not the preferred solution given we have other Jetty instances and other batch processes that we'd like to go off a single instance of these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported this issue on the Jetty site at the following URL:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428097

Will continue to track further information about the configuration or the issue from there.

**UPDATE:**
- This issues has been resolved and merged into the Jetty 9.2 code base.  For version 9.1.5 we created a custom module that specifies all the .jar files in the directory and that is working fine (although not ideal).

The commonlib.mod file looks like:

```
#
# commonlib Module
#

[lib]
M:\commonlib\commons-codec-1.4.jar
M:\commonlib\commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
M:\commonlib\commons-io-2.3.jar
M:\commonlib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
M:\commonlib\commons-net-2.2.jar
M:\commonlib\commons-pool-1.6.jar
```

Used the command line to add the commonlib module to the start.ini file (although a manual edit would work just fine too).